# How to make resposive right nav bar icons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to keep some icons in left side and some in right side and so I did like this

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

But the problem is in mobile view the right side icons are coming down and remains at right botton and over all the nav bar size increases.Is it possible to keep the nav bars at right side in big screens but in small screens all the icons will come down

This is the [bootply](http://bootply.com/112092#)

Comment: @codingguru I am not using jquery mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using css [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) you can create your own class and use it intead of pull-right

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
   .your_class {
       float: left;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 501px) {
   .your_class {
      float: right;
   }
}
```

and then just use your class

```
(...)
<ul class="nav navbar-nav your_class">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>

</ul>
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer But I am not aware of media queries.Can you please update the bootply

Comment: There's a link on the answer that has everything you need to know about media queries, also bootply doesn't allow you to resize the screen to small resolutions.

Comment: There is a mobile view in bootply.Thanks

Comment: uh yeah, my bad, didn't see that

Comment: A little help see this http://bootply.com/112343 did after your answer,its not looking well.Can you please suggest me where to keep?

Comment: change the sizes to (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 768px)